# How and where to enable SSL using Rails on standard Pivotal Web Services

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, unicorn, pivotal-web-services

**Background:**
I have a small Rails application running on Pivotal Web Services with MongoDB in the background as the database layer.  I have used as much of the standards offered by Rails and PWS but have changed Webrick with Unicorn as the application server to allow for better scaling/multi-processing.

---

**My Challenge:**
My next challenge in my project is to introduce SSL and here is where i need some help.

---

**What Have I Found Already:**
I have found information on how to use SSL with Webrick, or Thin, Puma and Nginx but nothing on SSL with Unicorn.  I also have found that Webrick, Thin and Nginx are called Web Servers while Unicorn is typically called an Application Server with HTTP capabilities.

---

**Questions:**

- Do I need to add a web server in front of Unicorn to implement SSL
  between my browser clients and my PWS application, or can it be done
  in Unicorn as well?
- If i need to add a web server, is the PWS standard web server a good option, as i would be able to leverage the load balancing and horizontal scaling which i get standard with PWS?
- If i implement Nginx or another web server with my application, do i then loose the standard PWS load balancing features?

Comment: You will need to handle SSL termination *in-front* of the PWS load balancers (and there should be a secure connection between your SSL terminators and the PWS load balancers), not *behind* the load balancers (i.e. not at your application level).  This doc may be of help: https://docs.run.pivotal.io/marketplace/integrations/cloudflare/

Comment: That turned out to be the very simple and easy answer.  All it took was to uncomment the following line in config/environments/production.rb:   config.force_ssl = true.  That enabled SSL with the PWS load balancers as you stated.  Case Closed.

Comment: Cool!  You should write and accept your own answer, that will be helpful for the next person who has the same question.

Answer (score 0):

All it took was to uncomment the following line in config/environments/production.rb: config.force_ssl = true.

That enabled SSL between the client and the PWS load balancers.  Gotta love rails and gotta love Pivotal Web Services.